# Are POST requests cached in Django?

Tags: django, graphql, django-cache

I want to get some view cached depending on the POST data sent to it.

Does the `django.views.decorators.cache.cache_page` decorator do that automatically or do I need to tweak it somehow? In the latter case, how should I do that?

I'm trying to cache GraphQL POST requests.

Answer (score 5):

No, POST responses are never cached:

```
    if request.method not in ('GET', 'HEAD'):
        request._cache_update_cache = False
        return None  # Don't bother checking the cache.
```

(from `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` in django.middleware.cache).

You'll have to implement something yourself using the [low-level cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api). It's most unusual to cache a response to a POST request, since a POST request is meant to change things in the database and the result is **always** unique to the particular request. You'll have to think about what exactly you want to cache.

Comment: To give more context, I am trying to cache GraphQL requests that do not change anything in the database, but are requested by a POST method.

Comment: Take a look at how Django builds the cache key in `django.utils.cache.get_cache_key`. That'll give you an idea of how the url is combined with the headers to generate a unique cache key for the request. You'll have to add the post data to that.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom decorator which caches responses based on request path, query parameters, and posted data:

```py
# myproject/apps/core/caching.py

import hashlib
import base64
from functools import wraps

from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings


def make_hash_sha256(o):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(repr(make_hashable(o)).encode())
    return base64.b64encode(hasher.digest()).decode()


def make_hashable(o):
    if isinstance(o, (tuple, list)):
        return tuple((make_hashable(e) for e in o))

    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return tuple(sorted((k,make_hashable(v)) for k,v in o.items()))

    if isinstance(o, (set, frozenset)):
        return tuple(sorted(make_hashable(e) for e in o))

    return o


def cache_get_and_post_requests(duration=600):
    def view_decorator(view):
        @wraps(view)
        def view_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            # TODO: make the key also dependable on the user or cookies if necessary
            cache_key = "-".join((
                settings.CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX,
                make_hash_sha256((
                    request.path,
                    list(request.GET.items()),
                    list(request.POST.items()),
                    request.body,
                )),
            ))
            cached_response = cache.get(cache_key)
            if cached_response:
                return cached_response
            response = view(request, *args, **kwargs)
            cache.set(cache_key, response, duration)
            return response
        return view_wrapper
    return view_decorator
```

Then I can use it in the URL configuration like so:

```py
# myproject/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from myproject.apps.core.caching import cache_get_and_post_requests

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    # …
    path("graphql/", cache_get_and_post_requests(60*5)(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
)
```

Comment: You're ignoring the HTTP headers. E.g. your solution wouldn't work if the response contains translated text or localised numbers/dates etc...

Comment: Yes, there is some room for improvement :)

Comment: The languages in my case are controlled by the path prefix. I updated the urls.py example to reflect that.